# How can I ask my employer to pay me in Bitcoin?

Tags: salary, contracts, europe

I'd like to change my contract to get paid in Bitcoin but before I start discussion I'd like to figure out what would the procedure and legalities of this are in Europe.

1. Is it even legal?
2. Bitcoin's value is highly fluctuating, how to deal with that?
3. How should the contract be formed?
4. How can I convince my employer to be on board with this?
5. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same as to be paid with a traditional currency and immediately buy bitcoins? You even have the control to decide if/when/how much...

Comment: Thats probably what the employer will say

Comment: *Why* do you want to be paid in bitcoin?

Comment: It obfuscate the work for the book keeping, I expect the employer get a warning from an audit by paying salaries by bitcoin. Also, the accountants will halways have to deal with the fluctuation for each transaction, increasing they work. What the employer wins in this deal?

Comment: Why would your employer expose them selfs to the risk and effort of having to deal in an additional currency, a wildly fluctuating and somewhat illicit one at that, for basically no reason. I'm going to -1 this, because 'Europe' is not one place with one set of procedures and legalities.

Comment: @NathanCooper - Is there anything illegal about BitCoin, itself? Or are you referring to the ability for it to be used to mask illegal exchanges of funds?

Answer (score 13):

Europe does not have unified laws, but at least in Germany, that would simply be illegal.

Gewerbe-Ordnung (GewO §107):

> (1) Das Arbeitsentgelt ist in Euro zu berechnen und auszuzahlen.

*(Translation: payment has to be calculated and payed out in Euros)*

Any kind of bonuses can be whatever you want to be (money, a cruise, bitcoin, a party or whatever), but your payment for regular work *has* to be Euro.

I would expect other European countries to have similar laws, so you cannot cheat on taxes or minimum wage. I mean how would one enforce minimum wage if you could pay your employees in french fries or trading cards?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you write a sentence on email? Ths is the ask part.

Expect to be ignored. It may be illegal (like germany) or complex. Take the euro to your bank, send them to a broker (except what you need), buy bitcoin.

So...

1: Possibly, possibly not (i.e. Germany: No.

2: Your problem. You get Euro X, this would result in the employer taking off taxes and then buying from taht Euro X bitcoin, which he sends you. Fluctuations are not his problem.

3: Depends on country. In germany not at all.

4: Not at all? Iti s one of those battles not worth fighting. As employer, particularly one in a non crypto field, I would rather replace you than put that trouble into my accounting side (and I say that are someone invested very heavily in bitcoin). PLease take my local currency and do with it waht you want, but do not bother my backoffice with it.

5: Yes. It is.